# Using Camel to stream output from a POST to a URL

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to use the Camel Stream Component to read output of a POST to a URL? Something like: `<to uri="stream:url?url=http://localhost:8080/mycontext/myservlet"/>`
I tried this but it did not work. I need to post a JSON object to a URL and process a huge payload being returned, so I need it to be streamed to a file without loading it all in memory first. Are there alternatives in the CAMEL DSLs or should I be using a bean somehow, e.g. using a HttpUrlConnection, to do the streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [http module](https://camel.apache.org/http.html) - it does support POST requests and furthermore will give you an `InputStream` in return.

As long as your route does not force Camel to auto-convert the message payload to `String`, you are free to implement any proprietary streaming logic in your handler. In other words, make sure your handler, e.g. a bean method, uses `InputStream` rather than `String` in its method signature.

Comment: I tried the file (uri:file) component (as well as stream:file) as a handler for the http module and it didn't start creating the file until the whole payload was read. I'll try the bean method next though.

Comment: Ok, I tried the bean method with the InputStream signature, but it still doesn't stream. Please see my revised question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709979/streaming-to-a-file-from-an-http-post-request-in-camel

Comment: I am afraid, http component is not suitable after all (and my answer is not correct). I checked the source code and it ALWAYS does a complete transfer of the producer response into the camel cache. I also checked the Netty module, but the source code is way more complex, so I am not sure what it does exactly. I would advice you to check it out anyway - it looks promising. The servlet module is not suitable, since it only supports consuming and you need producing.

Comment: Accepted because I didn't know you could do a POST. Also, I tried the netty module (see follow up post linked) and it appears to always cache the download as well, unfortunately. This is Camel ver 2.16.0.

Comment: @awgtek did you actually try out your InputStream signature bean together with the Camel stream component. According to the Camel forum this should work: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Is-There-a-way-to-treat-a-large-file-td5774055.html

Comment: I don't quite follow. what I did try though is in my follow up question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709979/streaming-to-a-file-from-an-http-post-request-in-camel?lq=1